# Syntax in HISTORY_IGNORE?

Tags: zsh

I am trying to ignore some sensitive commands from being saved in history file in zsh.

```
HISTSIZE=1000                 # 1000 lines of history within the shell
SAVEHIST=1000                 # 1000 lines of history in $HISTFILE
HISTFILE=${HOME}/.zsh_history # Save history to ~/.zsh_history
## Ignore save in $HISTFILE, but still in the shell
HISTORY_IGNORE='([bf]g *|cd ..|l[a,l,s,h,] *|less *|vi[m,] *)'
```

But it still shows in history file:

```
% rm .zsh_history 
% ls              
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  peda  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
% l
Desktop/  Documents/  Downloads/  Music/  peda/  Pictures/  Public/  Templates/  Videos/
% cat .zsh_history
ls
l
cat .zsh_history
```

I have read the [zshparam](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/zshparam.1.html) page but it doesn't help.

Is the part `l[a,l,s,h,] *` right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`l[a,l,s,h,] *` does not match `l` because `[]` is not a comma-separated list of things to expand to - that's the syntax for brace expansion. With `[...]`, `[a,l,s,h,]` is the same as `[alsh,]` and does not mean any of `alsh` or nothing. You need `l[alsh]#`.

For `ls`, the space seems to be breaking this match, even though everything after that is optional. So in practice, this seems to ignore `ls` only if it has an argument:

```
~ ls foo
ls: cannot access 'foo': No such file or directory
~ tail ~/.histfile
HISTORY_IGNORE='([bf]g *|cd ..|l[a,l,s,h,]*|less *|vi[m,] *)'
l
tail ~/.histfile
l
tail ~/.histfile
```

It seems you need to make the `*` optional as well:

```
HISTORY_IGNORE='([bf]g *|cd ..|l[alsh]#( *)#|less *|vim# *)'
```

Comment: Do you know where to find the full documentation about `HISTORY_IGNORE`?

Comment: @MarkJ.Adams zshparam is about it. That said, the manpage mentions `[[ $1 != ${~HISTORY_IGNORE} ]]` in the function on removing entries from history, and I think that test matches up pretty well with the actual behaviour of `HISTORY_IGNORE` on command lines